# How to make a web app that works without javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I'd like to build a webapp with a real rich user interface. (think graphs that can be manipulated with mouse gestures).

In order to be nice to environments that don't support java script (crawlers, other computers), the application should work without javascript just as well. I mean it should offer all the features but in a low fidelity kind of way. Just forms and links that is.

How do I go about this? Are there libraries available for something like this?

For the java script UI I'm currently considering extJS, but that isn't fixed at all.

Comment: You know webcrawlers don't play with your site, right?

Comment: If you want real-time interaction without Javascript, that means using Flash or some other similar technology.

Comment: Or Silverlight ... /ducksAndRunsForTheHills

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if you want a real-time interactive website, Javascript is the option that's likely to be supported and enabled on most browsers. That is, I can't imagine a person that would surf with Javascript blocked / disabled but leave Flash enabled.

Comment: @Inerdia you'd be surprised, I sometimes disable javascript when i'm on a low connection going through my phone and dont often disable flash as everyone uses the satay/swfobject embeds. But I'm probably a bit weird :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with something that works with plain links and forms (e.g. where values are typed instead of pointed at), then layer JS based drag and drop on top of it.

See:

- [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)
- [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: While those are some wise words, it's worth to note that it won't fix the OP's issue, where he seems to want a dynamic website without scripting as opposed to a website that degrades nicely.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras — Really? The question does say "it should offer all the features but in a low fidelity kind of way. Just forms and links that is"

Answer (score -1):

Flash but perhaps thats cheating, SVG is another good idea as a fallback as no-script browsers are unlikely to be webkit ones.
Also perhaps making image on the fly through the server using ImageMagick or GDLIB so images/graphs etc are made when the page is requested. It's kinda old school, but so is expecting no-script browsers ;-)

One thing I'd say about EXT: It's great but it's heavy and it takes a long time to get your head around as it really doesn't feel 'open' more like a bunch of components that you can configure but not alter.

If you want SVG and javascript perhaps look at Raphael and it's graphing/charting brother gRaphael :
http://g.raphaeljs.com/

http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Flash is even less accessible than JavaScript.